# Ways to write $n=p^k$ as a product of integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let's say that $F(n)$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a product of integers greater than $1$. For example, $F(12)=4$ since $12=2\cdot 2 \cdot 3$, $12=2\cdot 6$, $12=3\cdot 4$ and $12=12$.

Given $n=p^k$ where $p$ is a prime number, what is the value of $F(n)$? I know how to manage this problem when $n=p_1\cdots p_k$ where $p_1,\ldots , p_k$ are different primes (the result is $B(k)$, where $B(n)$ is the Bell-Number), but how can I do it in this case?

**Note**: The order of the factors does not matter; that is, $a\cdot b$ and $b \cdot a$ do not count as different ways to write a number

Comment: If the factors (but not necessarily $n$ itself) are required to be prime powers, then what one would get is the number of abelian groups of order $n$.

Comment: the factors are  $p^ab^b..p^n$ where $a+b+...+n= k$ so this is just the same number as the number of ways to express $k$ as a sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly, any factor of $n$ will be of the form $p^m$ for some $m\le k$. The question thus is equivalent to asking how many ways are there to write $k$ as the sum of positive integers, where order doesn't matter. This is simply the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $k$.

I'll admit that I'm not super familiar with partitions myself, so I'm not sure if there's a nice formula for this; I don't believe there is, though.

Comment: The number of partitions of $k$ is also the number of abelian groups of order $n=p^k$, by the way.

Comment: There are at least nice recursive formulas for the partition function.

Comment: Why partitions of $n$ and not partitions of $k$? I don't get this

Comment: @fdez Basically, it's just because we're only looking at the exponent now: If we have a way to write $n=p^k=p^{a_1}p^{a_2}\dots p^{a_m}$, then we have $k=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_m$, which is just a partition of $k$.

Comment: @boink yes I understand that, but in your solution you say "partitions of $n$" and in the previous comment you talk about "partitions of $k$". I am confused

Comment: @fdez ahhh whoops, you're right—that's a typo! I'll edit the post

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, the number is given by the number of partitions.
We add two more facts about it.

1 - By the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups the number of abelian groups of order $n=p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k}$ is the product of the partition numbers of $n_i$.

2- For the partition function $p(n)$ there are recursion formulas, asymptotic formulas and even an exact formula. The latter one is due to Rademacher (going back to work of Hardy and Ramanujan). We have

$$p(n) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{k}\ A_k(n)\ F_k'(n),$$
with

$$A_k(n) = \sum_{0 \le m < k, \gcd(m, k) = 1} e^{i\pi\left(s(m, k) - 2nm/k\right)}$$
and

$$F_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - \frac{1}{24}}} \sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{k} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\left(x - \frac{1}{24}\right)}\right)$$

Here $s(m, k)$ is the *Dedekind sum* given by

$$s(m, k) = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)\right)\left(\left(\frac{mn}{k}\right)\right)$$

where $((x))$ is the sawtooth function

$$((x)) = \begin{cases}
x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}, &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}\\
0, &\mbox{if }x \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$$